# Accordion Bootstrap in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I have to make accordion like in bootstrap (using only jQuery without JavaScript code from bootstrap) but problem is that I can't hide elements after click. My code is [here](http://%C2%ADgoo.gl/UkSo9o).

If you click code verifies that `div` has class but he return false every time. 
What could be a reason?

Comment: show what you have done so far...

Comment: link --> goo.gl/UkSo9o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function accordion() {
            if ($(this).find('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
                $(this).find('.panel-collapse').removeClass("in");
            } else {
                $(this).find('.panel-collapse').addClass("in");
            };
        };
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you so much @FilipdeTillier. If you don't mind, Can I have an up vote ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#accordion').find('.panel-heading').click(function(){
 
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
 
    //Hide the other panels
  $(".panel-collapse").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
 
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseContainer1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseContainer2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseContainer3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
```